Output a resource ID from an array using BICEP
I have a very simple BICEP template that creates a virtual network and a couple of subnets. The subnets are created using an array.
I'm trying to output the subnet IDs individually so that I can use them later. However, I'm struggling to achieve this, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Please, may someone help me understand how to output the IDs of subnets?
Below is the template and parameter file.
Template
//PARAMETERS
@description('Enter the virtual network name.')
param vnetName string
@description('Enter the deployment region.')
param location string
@description('Enter the virtual network address space.')
param addressPrefixes array
@description('Enter the subnet names and address spaces.')
param subnets array

//RESOURCE
resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2019-11-01' = {
  name: vnetName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: addressPrefixes
    }
    subnets: subnets
  }
}

//OUTPUTS
output subnetId array = [for (name, i) in subnets: {
  resourceId: virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[i].id
}]

PARAMETER FILE
using './virtualNetwork.bicep'

param vnetName = 'vnet-hub-uks-01'

param location = 'uksouth'

param addressPrefixes = [
  '10.0.0.0/16'
]

param subnets = [
  {
    name: 'subnet-1'
    properties: {
      addressPrefix: '10.0.0.0/24'
    }
  }
  {
    name: 'subnet-2'
    properties: {
      addressPrefix: '10.0.1.0/24'
    }
  }
  {
    name: 'subnet-3'
    properties: {
      addressPrefix: '10.0.2.0/24'
    }
  }
]


Output
The output below shows all three resource IDs in a single output, but I would like them to be shown individually.
[{"resourceId":"/subscriptions/d5f2dcf8-ab3f-47aa-9ec3-9c5aba4b909f/resourceGroups/rg-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-hub-uks-01/subnets/subnet-1"},{"resourceId":"/subscriptions/d5f2dcf8-ab3f-47aa-9ec3-9c5aba4b909f/resourceGroups/rg-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-hub-uks-01/subnets/subnet-2"},{"resourceId":"/subscriptions/d5f2dcf8-ab3f-47aa-9ec3-9c5aba4b909f/resourceGroups/rg-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-hub-uks-01/subnets/subnet-3"}]


The issue in your Bicep template is with how you're trying to access the subnet IDs in the output section. The subnets array in your parameter file is an array of objects, so when you try to access virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[i].id, it's expecting i to be an integer index, but you're passing an object. @Jon

@VinayB, I've managed to output the subnet resource IDs into a single output. Still, I'm not knowledgeable enough to get it to output each subnet ID individually or use the outputted array as input for other resources.

output subnetIds array = [
for subnet in subnets: {
id: concat(
'/subscriptions/',
subscription().subscriptionId,
'/resourceGroups/',
resourceGroup().name,
'/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/',
vnetName,
'/subnets/',
subnet.name
)
}
]
try this once by replacing the output configuration and try again @Jon

@VinayB I have managed to get the output working using a new output block; see the updated template above. My issue is that all subnet IDs are in a single output. I was hoping to get them out individually.

Is this the output format you're expecting! link @jon check with the link once

@VinayB No, I was looking at getting them to appear as individual outputs rather than all within a single output.

For that to happen you may need multiple output modules in the bicep file is that changes okay for you? @Jon  check with this once?

Can you please check with these screenshots or can you please specify how exactly is your output should look like @Jon
